# Segmentation fault(core dumped) in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, segmentation-fault, coredump

I am getting a segmentation fault in my code which does insertion of data in a singly linked list and later prints the same . I have no idea whatsoever from where it is coming . Here is my code . Any kind of suggestions or advice are most welcomed . Thank you .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void insert_data(int data);
void print_list();
typedef struct node{
    int info;
    struct node* next;
    }mynode; 

mynode *head=NULL,*tail=NULL,*ptr = NULL;
int main()
{
        int nodes,i;
    int data;
    printf("how many nodes u want to insert");
    scanf("%d",&nodes);
    for(i=0;i<nodes;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter data");
        scanf("%d",&data);
        insert_data(data);
    }
    print_list();
    return 0;
}
void insert_data(int data)
{
    ptr = (mynode *)malloc(sizeof(mynode));
    (*ptr).info = data;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
    (*ptr).next = NULL;
    head = ptr;
    tail = ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("inside else");
        (*ptr).next=NULL;
        (*tail).next = ptr;
        tail = ptr;
    }
    return;
}
void print_list()
{   
    ptr = head;
    while((*ptr).next != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",(*ptr).info);
        ptr = (*ptr).next;
    }   
    printf("%d",(*ptr).info);
}
```

Comment: [sigh] show us what debugging you have done and what you found out.  When you ran this code under your debugger, which line raised the segfault?

Comment: Where did you put the NULL element you are looking for in `while((*ptr).next != NULL)` ? ;-)

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. **Use the debugger** (`gdb`) and perhaps [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 1):

`if(head=NULL)` should be `if(head==NULL)`.

Moreover, using too many global variables is often discouraged. You can decleare `ptr` as a local variable in each function. Doing so will prevent weird interactions between functions.

For instance :

```
void print_list()
{   
  mynode* ptr2 = head; // ptr2 is local : it only exist in this function.
  while((*ptr2).next != NULL)
  {
    printf("%d",(*ptr2).info);
    ptr2 = (*ptr2).next;
  }   
  printf("%d",(*ptr2).info);
}
```

The function above fails if the list is empty : adding a test on `head` could be a good thing !

Finally, the function can be modified to handle any list `mynode*`, not just `head` :

```
void print_list(mynode* somelisthead)
{   
  if(somelisthead==NULL){printf("empty list\n");return;}
  mynode* ptr2 = somelisthead; // ptr2 is local : it only exist in this function.
  while((*ptr2).next != NULL)
  {
    printf("%d ",(*ptr2).info);
    ptr2 = (*ptr2).next;
  }   
  printf("%d",(*ptr2).info);
}
```

It is now called in main as `print_list(head);`

The code you posted calls `malloc()` : this allocates memory for each node. I guess that writing a function using `free()` to release the memory is the following step !

Does the following code still exhibit a segmentation fault ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


typedef struct node{
    int info;
    struct node* next;
}mynode; 

void print_list(mynode* somelisthead);
// why ** ? because head and tail are modified by the function. Therefore, passing by argument is required, and a pointer to head named phead is provided to the function.
void insert_data(int data, mynode** phead,mynode** ptail);

mynode *head=NULL,*tail=NULL;
int main()
{
    int nodes,i;
    int data;
    printf("how many nodes u want to insert ?\n");
    scanf("%d",&nodes);
    for(i=0;i<nodes;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter data\n");
        scanf("%d",&data);
        insert_data(data,&head,&tail);
    }
    print_list(head);
    return 0;
}
void insert_data(int data, mynode **phead,mynode ** ptail)
{
    mynode* ptr = malloc(sizeof(mynode));
    if(ptr==NULL){printf("malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    ptr->info = data;  // ptr-> is equivalent to (*ptr).
    if((*phead) == NULL)
    {
        ptr->next = NULL;
        *phead = ptr;
        *ptail = ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("inside else\n");
        ptr->next=NULL;
        (*ptail)->next = ptr;
        *ptail = ptr;
    }
    return;
}

void print_list(mynode* somelisthead)
{   
    if(somelisthead==NULL){printf("empty list\n");return;}
    mynode* ptr = somelisthead; // ptr is local : it only exist in this function.
    while(ptr->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",ptr->info);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }   
    printf("%d\n",ptr->info);
}
```

I did not check the return value of `scanf()`. But it would be another good idea...

Answer (score 0):

Running your code on ubuntu gcc gives no segmentation fault.
So your code is correct.

I/O of your code

```
how many nodes u want to insert5
Enter data2
Enter data3
inside elseEnter data5
inside elseEnter data2
inside elseEnter data1
inside else23521
```

Can you provide a testcase in which your code gives Segmentation fault.